# Show that all solutions remain in the interval for all time

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I really have no idea on how to get started with these, there's no similar example in my book. Do I need to compute $\frac{dy}{dx}$? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Maybe there's just some theorem I am not aware of

Show that all solutions $x(t),y(t)$ which start inside the given interval ($x>0,y>0$ for part a,$x>0$ for part b, $x^2+y^2=1$ for part c) must remain there for all time:

a. $$\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2+ysinx$$ $$\frac{dy}{dt}=-1+xy+cosy$$ $$x>0,y>0$$

1st attempt: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-1+xy+cosy}{x^2+ysinx}$

I can't remember how to solve for this since it's not separable

b. $$\frac{dx}{dt}=y(e^x-1)$$ $$\frac{dy}{dt}=x+e^y$$ $$x>0$$

1st attempt: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+e^y}{y(e^x-1)}$

c. $$\frac{dx}{dt}=-1-y+x^2$$ $$\frac{dy}{dt}=x+xy$$ $$x^2+y^2=1$$

1st attempt: 
I just substituted...I don't think this is right though

$\frac{dx}{dt}=-1-y+x^2$
$\frac{d(x^2+y^2)}{dt}=1-y+(x^2+y^2)^2$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=x+xy$
$\frac{d(x^2+y^2)}{dt}=x+x(x^2+y^2)$

hint: compute $\frac{d(x^2+y^2)}{dt}$

Comment: What's "the given interval"?

Comment: @naslundx it varies for each part, i wrote it in a b and c under the differential equations

Comment: Which interval?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis x>0,y>0 for a, x>0 for b, $x^2+y^2=1$ for c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints.

In a. If $x$ or $y$ vanishes for some $t_0$, then they stay zero, and due to uniqueness, they are zero everywhere - contraction.

In b. Note that if $x(t_0)= 0$, for some $t_0$, then $x\equiv 0$, again due to uniqueness.

In c. $(x^2+y^2)'=-2x(x^2+y^2-1)=0$.